# Counting the number of people working at a given time

Tags: tableau-api

I have data the shows when employees log in and when they log out. I call the duration they are logged in "Ready" time and the time they are logged off as "Not Ready" time. What I want to do is have a continuous, gradient timeline that shows how many people are in the ready state.

Some notes about the data:

- The data has a start time and an end time. Each record is unique for the employee and the start time?
- I unfortunately cannot post this data as it does not belong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that your data is something like this

```
employee    start_time  end_time
E1  7/7/2017  10:03:10 AM   7/7/2017  18:03:10 AM
E2  7/7/2017  10:10:10 AM   7/7/2017  18:03:10 AM
E3  7/7/2017  10:13:10 AM   7/7/2017  18:03:10 AM
E1  7/7/2017  11:03:10 AM   7/7/2017  19:03:10 AM
E2  7/7/2017  10:30:10 AM   7/7/2017  18:03:10 AM
```

In that case I would follow these steps:

- Check if start_time & end_time columns are not in 'timestamp' format then right click it and go to 'Change data type' to select 'Date & Time'
- Create a parameter `Select_Report_DateTime`. In parameter window select Data  type = 'Date & Time'; Display format = 'Automatic'; Allowable values = 'All'
- Right click this parameter and select 'Show parameter control'
- Create calculated field `default_date_time` as `#1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM#`. If it's not in 'timestamp' format then right click it and go to 'Change data type' to select 'Date & Time'
- Create calculated field `Report_DateTime_formatted` as

---

```
IF [Select_Report_DateTime] == [default_date_time] then now()
ELSE [Select_Report_DateTime]
END
```

---

- Create a calculated field `Users(inReadyState)` as

---

```
IF (([Report_DateTime_formatted] >= [start_time]) & 
    ([Report_DateTime_formatted] < [end_time])) THEN "Yes"
ELSE "No"
END
```

---

- Now drag `Users(inReadyState)` in 'Columns', `CNT[employee]` in 'Rows' and 'Marks' as Bar.
- You can very well play around with this model to get the o/p as per your specific requirement.

*Don't forget to let us know if it helped :)*

Comment: Just a little nit. In the last calculated field, all you need to keep is the Boolean condition. You don't need the if/then/else at all. Then the calculated field has a Boolean datatype. Boolean are first class datatypes.