# Query on Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I am a new to Tableau and having some issues with it.I am  Using a parameter to filter  month data across Sheets connected to different Data Sources.

I want to Filter  Current Month Data Automatically  when the dashboard starts.

Can anyone guide me on how to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

T

Answer (score 1):

The critical aspect of your question is that you are filtering ***multiple*** data sources using a parameter. Given that, the most straightforward approach is to define a boolean calculated field in each data source, called say Within_Date_Range.

Each of those calculated fields should compare the appropriate Date field in that data source to the selected parameter value and return true or false to indicate whether the current record should be included in the query. (Parameters are scoped to the workbook and visible from all data sources)

Place the [Within_Date_Range] field for data source X on the filter shelf for the worksheets that use that data source X. Check the true box of course.

Now when you change the parameter, all the worksheets filter accordingly.

Alternatively, you can abandon the use of a parameter. Define relationships between your data sources using the corresponding Date fields (under the data menu). Show a filter control for the date field for one of the worksheets and set the scope to "related data sources"

Comment: Nice approach! For detailed howto one would just need to tweak this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637703/counting-the-number-of-people-working-at-a-given-time/44965355#44965355) a bit. @Alex - pls correct me if you meant something different.

Answer (score 1):

Introduced in version 10.3 is a feature called Latest date preset. The release notes say "Start with up-to-date data. Set filters to display latest date values automatically, as soon as your workbook opens." Create a filter that spans applies across the data sources and use this new setting. The setting is in the filter dialog.

See https://www.tableau.com/new-features/10.3#tab-analytics-2

Comment: Oh great! So finally it seems that the most wanted feature has been accepted by Tableau guy :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

- Create a calculated field `Date_Filter` as

  `lookup(min([Your_Date_Field]),0)`
- Drag this to 'Filter'; select 'relative date' option and choose last 1
  month (because you wanted to show just the current month data by default).
- Right click this filter and select "Apply to selected worksheet" and
  choose sheets in which you want this filter to be applied on the
  dashboard.Viola!

With this solution you can very well see current month's data by default and can go back to as many time periods you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention .My requirement is such when the Dashboard loads it should show for the current month .The user should be able to select and view for ither months too  after the page loads.

Comment: Yes... no problem. You just need to select 'Show filter' on above defined filter `Date_Filter` in 'Filter' section. That's it!

Comment: This will include  ALL months in the query, but only display the selected one - because it uses the lookup() function. That can hurt performance in many cases. Experiment with leaving out the lookup() and min() calls around your Date field

Comment: @Alex This would be easiest option to achieve required result. Otherwise if performance factor is to be considered then I would suggest to go with "Parameter" way (hint - it can be achieved by tweaking the solution mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637703/counting-the-number-of-people-working-at-a-given-time/44965355#44965355))

Comment: @Prem, I still don't see the value of using lookup() and min() in this context - unless your goal is to fetch all the aggregate data to the client, and then allow to quickly switch which is displayed and which is hidden. (i.e. pay a one-time up front query cost to make potential future interactivity fast). For a set of large data sources with many years of data that would be wasteful. Not trying to be hostile. If you have a good reason to use a table calc here, I'd love to understand the benefit.

Comment: @Alex - In my earlier comment I proposed another approach in case performance constraints are there. But to answer your concern, if the backend DB is Hive/ Impala (since we are talking about big data!) then lookup() approach would be very handy. In these cases any query is converted into batch job (mapreduce etc) and it takes time to display result on the frontend so it would be a wise decision to fetch all data in one shot so that the user don't have to wait everytime he/ she wants to see data in different time periods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Prem. Like most performance issues, the details matter and the best choice can depend on the circumstances. I believe fetching all data in one shot pays off in the case you describe. It could also be an unnecessary cost if the user seldom switches months.